# If $D \subset \mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is an open connection....

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, multivalued-functions

> a) If $D \subset \mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is an open connection. Show that if $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are argument branches in $D$, then there is $k \in Z$ such that $\theta_1(z) = \theta_2(z) + 2k\pi,\, \forall z \in D$.
>
> b) Show that there is no logarithm branch in $\mathbb C \setminus\{0\}$.

I don't think I understand this matter.

a) What I know: An argument branch in $D \subseteq \mathbb C - \{0\}$ is a continuous function $f:D \to \mathbb R$ such that
\begin{align}
z &= |z| \, \bigl (\cos(f(z)) + i \sin(f(z)) \bigr) \\
\implies 
z &= |z| \, 
\bigl( \cos(\operatorname{Im}(L(z)) ) 
+ i \sin(\operatorname{Im} (L(z))) \bigr) 
\end{align}
but $\theta = \operatorname{Im} (L(z))$, and
$z = e^{L(z)} = |z| \, 
\bigl( \cos(\theta(z)) + i \sin(\theta(z)) \bigr)$.

I also know that: Let $D \subseteq \mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$ be an open one are equivalent:

1. There is a branch $L$ of $\log z$ in $D$.
2. There is a branch $\theta$ in $\arg z$ in $D$.

And by hypothesis there are $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, so there are \begin{align} 
L(z_1) = \log(z_1) + i\theta(z_1) 
&\implies e^{L(z_1)} = e^{\log(z_1)} e^{ i\theta(z_1)}, \\ 
L(z_2) = \log(z_2) + i\theta(z_2) 
&\implies e^{L(z_2)} = e^{\log(z_2)} e^{i\theta( z_2)}. 
\end{align}
That's it, I completely crashed.

Is question b) correct? Not the opposite of the proposition Let $f: D \subseteq \mathbb C\setminus \{ 0 \} \to \mathbb C $, open connected $D$, a logarithm branch on $D$. So every logarithm branch in $D$ is of the form $f(z) + 2k\pi i, \forall \in \mathbb Z$.

Grateful for the attention.

Comment: I corrected what I believe was a typo in the displayed math after "And by hypothesis..." by inserting the `\implies` arrows. Please edit if this correction was made in error.

Comment: You probably mean a domain,  or an open, simply connected set; not a connection, which is usually something different.

Comment: You need a branch cut.  There's no cut in $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$.